# MYSQL - adding a fixed number to already populated data

Tags: mysql, database, field, insert-update

I've been trawling SO and cant find what i'm after:

I need to change some order_id numbers in a table, by simply adding a set number ( eg 40) to the existing set of order_id.

IE i have order_id set to 100 but i need to change it to 140. Simple for few bits of data, but i have over a 1000 and cant work how to +40 to each number.

I'm assuming something like:

```
UPDATE table SET order_id = number THEN +40
```

Obviously this is wrong, but i cant find a simple way to do it. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want this:

```
update t
    set order_id = 140
    where order_id = 100;
```

This changes all occurances of `order_id` that has the value of 100.

If you have a range, it might be:

```
update t
    set order_id = order_id + 40
    where order_id between 100 and 1000;
```

(or whatever the appropriate range is).

You can also list them out individually, but that is a lot of work for 1000 values.

Comment: works well except for duplicate issue. Is there a way to start at the highest value first so the duplicate doesnt occur?

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE your_table
SET order_id = order_id + 40
```